# Efficiently create CSV file reports on the fly without slowing a node.js server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, api, csv, azure

I have a Node.js express API, hosted on an Azure App Service, serving up data from an SQL server database. A new requirement is to export reports based on customisable data. These should be CSV files generated on the fly.

The issue I am facing is that the CSV files, in certain circumstances, will be quite large (500,000 lines maybe). Its not hard for me to create these files, then maybe upload them to Blob storage, or serve them straight back to the user. However, as you can imagine, thats gonna take some load on the server. This API is serving about 500 Post/Get requests a minute. The single threaded nature of Node will mean it will take the server to a crawl when someone requests a CSV file like that.

I need some advice on what to do instead. My thoughts were to spin up a new application, on a new server (perhaps one written in ASP.NET?) that is responsible for creating CSV files. It exposes an end point which receives the parameters to create the file, then responds with either the file, or a link. But because its a separate server (and a separate thread if I did something like .NET) it wouldn't slow down the Node server when waiting for a response. This does seem like quite a lot of work however. Is there something simpler? I am open to any services that can connect directly to the SQL database and generate reports (so I can give that to the client instead of bespoke reports I would need to hard code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use another process, you can write your CSV generation code so that it uses `setImmediate` to schedule generation in chunks. Then it will yield intermittently so the thread can handle other requests.

```
const chunkSize = 1000;
function generateCSV(rows, cb) {
  const csv = [];
  function handleChunk(rows, rest) {
    for (let row of rows) {
      csv.push(`${rows[i].field1},${rows[i].field2}`);
    }
    if (rest.length) {
      setImmediate(handleChunk, rest.slice(0, chunkSize), rest.slice(chunkSize));
    } else {
      cb(null, csv.join('\n'));
    }
  }
  handleChunk(rows.slice(0, chunkSize), rows.slice(chunkSize));
}
```

Comment: This is great to know. I did not know of setImmediate and its much more elegant and relevant than setTimeout. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is not related to CSV file manipulation. 
It is dealing with huge tasks. Because that node.js is single threaded, a huge task can **"block"** the server.

The solution is to cut down huge tasks into smallest ones.

You can do that using `setTimeout()` function.

**Exemple** :

Without cutting down the task *(Task 2 et 3 gonna be waiting until task 1 is finished)*

```
[                     Task 1                            ][Task 2][   Task  3  ]
```

---

Using `setTimeout()`

```
[ Task 1.0 ][ Task 1.1 ][Task 2][ Task 1.2 ][   Task  3  ][ Task 1.3 ][ Task 1.4 ]
```

The tasks will not get blocked

Answer (score 0):

(I wrote this not realizing you're using Azure App Service. I'm not sure if Azure App Service allows child_process.fork. If not, this is the wrong answer for you, though it may help people on a different platform.)

Another solution is to use [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to do the heavy task in another process:

```
// worker.js
process.on('message', msg => {
  process.send(makeCSV(msg));
});

// server.js
const cp = require('child_process');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const child = cp.fork('./worker.js');
  child.on('message', csv => {
    res.send(csv);
  });
  child.send(req.params);
});
```

Forking a process is rather heavy. If you expect to handle a lot of CSV request, then rather than launching a new process for every request, you can create a pool of workers when your app first starts. Googling led me to https://github.com/thisandagain/fork-pool which appears to handle the pool for you.

If these expensive CSV requests are relatively rare, https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster might also solve your problem. This starts multiple server processes, so if one or two get busy making a CSV file, you'll still have others free to handle the stream of other requests.